# Grails wslite SOAP params result in Unmarshalling error

Tags: web-services, grails, soap

I'm trying to use wslite (0.7.2.0) with Grails (2.4.4) to consume a SOAP web service.  I was able to get the example to work:

```
withSoap(serviceURL: 'http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/US/Dates/USHolidayDates.asmx') {
    def response = send(SOAPAction: 'http://www.27seconds.com/Holidays/US/Dates/GetMothersDay') {
        body {
            GetMothersDay(xmlns: 'http://www.27seconds.com/Holidays/US/Dates/') {
                year(2011)
            }
        }
    }

    println response.GetMothersDayResponse.GetMothersDayResult.text()
}
```

But whenever I try to hit another endpoint that requires parameters, I get an Unmarshall exception.

My code:

```
withSoap(serviceURL: 'http://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/awdbWebService/services?wsdl') {
    def response = send {
        body {
            getStations("xmlns": 'http://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/ns/awdbWebService') {
                stateCds(Arrays.asList("OR"))
                logicalAnd(true)
            }
        }
    }

    response.getStationsResponse.return.each{resp->
        println resp
    }
}
```

The exception:

```
Message
    soap:Client - Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/ns/awdbWebService", local:"stateCds").
    Expected elements are <{}elementCds>,<{}maxElevation>,<{}networkCds>,<{}heightDepths>,<{}ordinals>,<{}maxLongitude>,
    <{}minElevation>,<{}hucs>,<{}stateCds>,<{}minLatitude>,<{}countyNames>,<{}maxLatitude>,<{}minLongitude>,<{}stationIds>,<{}logicalAnd>
```

Comment: When I look at the WSDL, I see that the stateCds expects a String parameter. Instead of Arrays.asList("OR"), try just "OR".

Comment: yeah I tried using stateCds("OR") with the same exception

Comment: Try setting your soapAction to " " empty string. I have had instances in the past where if I did not defined soapAction, it blew up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `stateCds` and `logicalAnd` elements should not be namespaced.  The namespace you are applying to the `getStations` element is being inherited by those children elements.

Here is a working example that can be run from the Groovy Console:

```
@Grab(group='com.github.groovy-wslite', module='groovy-wslite', version='1.1.0')
import wslite.soap.*

def client = new SOAPClient('http://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/awdbWebService/services')
def response = client.send {
    body {
        'awdb:getStations'("xmlns:awdb": 'http://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/ns/awdbWebService') {
            stateCds('OR')
            logicalAnd(true)
        }
    }
}

assert !response.getStationsResponse.isEmpty()
```

Comment: Namspacing the children was the problem.  John's answer above works as expected.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

switched over to groovy-wslite-1.1.0 thinking maybe the plugin was the problem.  Unfortunately the same Unmarshalling exception is thrown when attempting to pass parameters. I was able to get the request to work with parameters by passing raw XML to the service.